# How can I finish activity after capture the screenshot of view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I need to close the activity with screenshot of subview.

Here is my code snippets for it:

```
private void returnBackWithSavedImage() {
    int permissionCheck = PermissionChecker.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Hide top/bottom sub views
        updateView(View.GONE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        parentImageRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                byte[] byteArray = null;
                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    if (parentImageRelativeLayout != null) {
                        parentImageRelativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        parentImageRelativeLayout.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, byteArrayOutputStream);
                        byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                    }

                    byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
                    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception var7) {
                    var7.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                if (byteArray != null) {
                    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    returnIntent.putExtra("image", imgString);
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }.start();
        //Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.save_image_succeed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        showPermissionRequest();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `finish();` is called but activity has never been closed.
If I run the following code it closes the activity.

```
private void returnBackWithSavedImage() {
    int permissionCheck = PermissionChecker.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    } else {
        showPermissionRequest();
    }
}
```

I am wrestling with this issue for whole day but I really can't resolve.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Could you plz attach some logcat when finish() runs.

Comment: Sorry @ihsan.gaozp there isn't any logs for that. I don't see any warnings or errors after finish runs.

Comment: I found it worked when u deleted the runnable impl. So maybe you should change finish() to getActivity().finish()

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp `getActivity()` doesn't work. It's actually inside the activity. Did you test and upload your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Simply moving your image capture process to a method will solve the problem. It looks like the `CountDownTimer` `onFinish()` didn't run in UI Thread.

So, change your code to something like this:

```
private void returnBackWithSavedImage() {
    int permissionCheck = PermissionChecker.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ...

        new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                captureImage();
            }
        }.start();
        ...
    } else {
        showPermissionRequest();
    }
}

private void captureImage() {

    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (parentImageRelativeLayout != null) {
            parentImageRelativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            parentImageRelativeLayout.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        }

        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception var7) {
        var7.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    if (byteArray != null) {
        String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        returnIntent.putExtra("image", imgString);
    }
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```